# Router-outlet is not a known element, lazy loading

Tags: angular, module, routes, lazy-loading

I have an angular project with AppModule and a feature module called PagesModule which is being lazy loaded, where i do some routing,

I want to create a new feature module paralel to the PagesModule and call it CustomersModule and then also do some other routing there.

Both my child modules (PagesModule and CustomersModule) are imported to the AppModule imports array.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    PagesModule,
    CustomersModule,
    NbChatModule.forRoot({
        messageGoogleMapKey: 'AIzaSyA_wNuCzia92MAmdLRzmqitRGvCF7wCZPY',
    }),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
],
```

Both have routing modules that import RouterModule.forChild(routes) and export RouterModule

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
 import { CustomersComponent } from './customers.component';
 import { AuthGuard } from '../auth/auth-guard.service';
 import { Roles } from '../shared/Constants';
 import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

 const routes: Routes = [{
path: '',
component: CustomersComponent,
children: [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { role: Roles.customer },
        component: DashboardComponent,
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
],
 }];

 @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
 })
 export class CustomersRoutingModule { }
```

And also both Modules do have the base component that would serve as the parent and contain the router-outlet which would be used to render a default  component (Dashboard) and others later.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MENU_ITEMS } from '../pages/pages-menu';

```
@Component({
selector: 'ngx-customer',
styleUrls: ['customers.component.scss'],
template: `
<ngx-one-column-layout>
  <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ngx-one-column-layout>
 `,
})
export class CustomersComponent {

menu = MENU_ITEMS;
}
```

Also my main app-routing module has routes configured as forRoot and lazy loaded modules set

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'auth-callback', component: AuthCallbackComponent },
    {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
        .then(m => m.PagesModule),
},
{
    path: 'customer',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module')
        .then(m => m.CustomersModule),
},
{
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: LoginComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'register',
            component: NbRegisterComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'request-password',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'reset-password',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
        },
    ],
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'auth' },
];
```

And I am still getting the error  is not a recognized component

I tried all of the suggested errors, tried creating all the files manually and also using ng g m customers --routing, but nothing helped, tried recompiling multiple times without success,
I'm wondering is there some configuration where i need to add this new feature module (CustomersModule) because i searched the whole project for PagesModule and added my CustomersModule to all the occurances.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using ngx-admin, nebula theme as a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using lazy loading modules why are you importing PagesModule or CustomerModule inside Appmodule which is already loaded via router.

Also have you added CustomerComponent in declaration in customer.module.ts file.

Can you try removing PagesModule or CustomerModule from appmodule and add CustomerComponent inside customer.module.ts file.

Comment: I had the dashboard in declaration so its not that.
Also, i removed those module from app.module and they are indeed not needed but the error is still there,
If i remove router-outlet from customer.component then everything works, once i put it back, i get the error, like the RouterModule is not there but u can see that i export it from customers-routing.module.ts..

If i just display <h1> works </h1> inside customer.component.ts then it works, but using imported module gives me the errors...

Comment: Have you imported customer.routing.module.ts file inside customer.module.ts file ?

Comment: Yes, both customersRoutingModule and RouterModule are there in the imports array, among other module that i use

Comment: It might be helpful if you try to upload your things here .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Comment: Seems to take ages to compile, I can add you to my private github repo if you want

Comment: you can remove it